# SQL: Stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-insert

I am implementing a library management system in SQL. I have the following table structure and some values inserted in them:

```
create table books
(
IdBook number(5),
NameBook varchar2(35),
primary key(IdBook)
);

create table users
(
IdUsers number(5),
NameUser varchar2(20),
primary key(IdUsers)
);

create table borrowed
(
IdBorrowed number(5),
IdUsers number(5),
IdBook number(5),
DueDate date,
DateReturned date,
constraint fk_borrowed foreign key(IdUsers) references users(IdUsers),
constraint fk_borrowed2 foreign key(IdBook) references books(IdBook)
);

insert into books values(0,'FairyTale');
insert into books values(1,'Crime and Punishment');
insert into books values(2,'Anna Karenina');
insert into books values(3,'Norwegian Wood');

insert into users values(01,'Robb Dora');
insert into users values(02,'Pop Alina');
insert into users values(03,'Grozavescu Teodor');
insert into users values(04,'Popa Alin');

insert into borrowed values(10,02,3,'22-Jan-2017',null);
insert into borrowed values(11,01,1,'25-Jan-2017','19-Dec-2016');
insert into borrowed values(12,01,3,'22-Jan-2017',null);
insert into borrowed values(13,04,2,'22-Jan-2017','13-Dec-2016');
```

What I want now is that my db to allow "borrowing" books for the users(i.e insert into the borrowed table) that have no unreturned books(i.e date returned is not null) and if they have unreturned books I want to abandon the whole process. I thought to implement this in the following way:

```
create or replace procedure borrowBook(IdBorrowed in number,IdUsers number,IdBook number,DueDate date,DateReturned date) as begin
if exists (SELECT u.IdUsers, u.NameUser, b.DateReturned
        FROM users u, borrowed b
        WHERE  u.IDUSERS = b.IdUsers and DateReturned is not null),
insert into borrowed values(IdBorrowed,IdUsers,IdBook,DueDate,DateReturned);
end borrowBook;
```

The above procedure does not check if the parameter I pass to this function is the same as the one in my select and I do not know how to do this and correctly insert a value in my table.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not name your parameters the same as columns also used inside the procedure.

You can also simplify your procedure to a single INSERT statement, no `IF` required:

```
create or replace procedure borrowBook(p_idborrowed in number, p_idusers number, p_idbook number, p_duedate date, p_datereturned date) 
as 
begin

  insert into borrowed (idborrowed, idusers, idbook, duedate, datereturned)
  select p_idborrowed, p_idusers, p_idbook, p_duedate, p_datereturned
  from dual
  where not exists (select * 
                    from users u
                      join borrowed b on u.idusers = b.idusers
                    and b.datereturned is not null);

end borrowBook;
```

It's also good coding style to explicitly list the columns for an `INSERT` statement. And you should get used to the explicit `JOIN` operator instead of using implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
create or replace procedure borrowBook (
    in_IdBorrowed in number,
    in_IdUsers number,
    in_IdBook number,
    in_DueDate date,
    in_DateReturned date
) as
    v_flag number;
begin
    select (case when exists (select 1
                              from borrowed b
                              where b.IdUsers = in_IdUsers and b.DateReturned is not null
                             )
                 then 1 else 0
            end)
    into v_flag
    from dual;

    if (flag = 0) then
        insert into borrowed     
            values(in_IdBorrowed, in_IdUsers, in_IdBook, in_DueDate, v_DateReturned);
    end if
end -- borrowBook;
```

Comment: if I try to run this I get the following errors: Error(10,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(12,49): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "IN_IDUSER": invalid identifier
Error(20,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(21,70): PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: @didi . . . That is called a "typo".

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
create or replace procedure borrowBook( p_IdBorrowed  in number   ,
                                        p_IdUsers        number   ,
                                        p_IdBook         number   ,
                                        p_DueDate        date     ,
                                        p_DateReturned   date        ) 
as 
begin
    if (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM borrowed
         WHERE  IDUSERS = p_IdUsers 
           AND DateReturned IS NULL) = 0 THEN

        insert into borrowed values (p_IdBorrowed   ,
                                     p_IdUsers      , 
                                     p_IdBook       , 
                                     p_DueDate      ,
                                     p_DateReturned   );
    end if ;
end borrowBook;
```